# Output isn't ordered properly

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

How to order the result by C, D, A, B and `pincode` chronologically?

Original result :

```
S  Pincode
== =======
A  001
B  002
C  003
D  004
D  005
C  006
B  007
A  008
```

Expected result:

```
S  Pincode
== =======
C  003
C  006

D  004
D  005

A  001
A  008

B  002
B  007
```

Code:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  sector,
  pincode 

FROM 
  sh_av_spform 

WHERE 

  type='ticket' and 
  status='new' and 
  date(`createdate`) = CURDATE()

ORDER BY  

  FIELD( sector,  'C','D','A','B' ) ASC 

limit 5
```

Above SQL, Gives sometimes, not correctly ordered pincode in chronological `sector`

Invalid output i get such as:

```
S  Pincode
== =======
C  003
C  006

D  005
D  004 <<< ???

A  001
A  008

B  007
B  002 <<< ???
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only order by one column. Add the second one too:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  sector,
  pincode 

FROM 
  sh_av_spform 

WHERE 

  type='ticket' and 
  status='new' and 
  date(`createdate`) = CURDATE()

ORDER BY  

  FIELD( sector,  'C','D','A','B' ) ASC,  
  pincode ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include `pincode` in your `ORDER BY` clause :

```
ORDER BY  
  FIELD( sector,  'C','D','A','B' )  , pincode
```

No need to write `ASC` as it is the default ordering.